# Update-grub errors after remaking bpool on 20.04

Tags: grub2, 20.04, zfs

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.  I lost the bpool and remade one
trying to follow the bpool parts of:

https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html

However, something is wrong when I try to run update-grub as I get errors like:
"dataset does not exist"
"didn't find any valid initrd or kernel"
"/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem"

These errors are marked with "#####" in the first section below.
Further below is the output of a number of commands that might help diagnose my problem.

I have not rebooted the system as I would like to see a good "update-grub" first.
Is there anyway to tell what grub-probe is saying "unknown filesystem" about?
The initrd and vmlinuz it finds it shows as on rpool and it seems it
should be getting current stuff from bpool.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?  Or what more should I do to try to figure it out?

Thanks,

-- Vince

```
> update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt
#####  cannot open 'bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_bn0dav': dataset does not exist
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_bn0dav
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_bn0dav
#####  cannot open 'bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_6w4i64': dataset does not exist
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_6w4i64
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_6w4i64
#####  cannot open 'bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_hclrw0': dataset does not exist
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_hclrw0
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_hclrw0
#####   Warning: didn't find any valid initrd or kernel.
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_78af4i
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_78af4i
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_2dlyc8
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt@autozsys_2dlyc8
#####  /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done

root@epp:/home/vince/bin# df | grep boot
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt                           1744640    92160   1652480   6% /boot
/dev/sda1                                          1032428    13296   1019132   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc1                                          1032428     7956   1024473   1% /boot/efi2
/dev/sdb1                                          1032428    13277   1019152   2% /boot/efi3
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/grub                      1658112     5632   1652480   1% /boot/grub


> cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#                
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation and /boot on bpool but nvme drive died
UUID=9403-E2A6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
UUID=5FFD-2417  /boot/efi2       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
UUID=7BBE-70D0  /boot/efi3       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
UUID=d3f4c789-9f90-414f-bf4f-dd543219a679 none  swap    discard 0   0


> cd /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache
root@epp:/etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache# ls
bpool  rpool
]0;root@epp: /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache
root@epp:/etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache# cat bpool 
bpool   /boot   off on  on  off on  off on  off -   none
bpool/BOOT  none    off on  on  off on  off on  off -   none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt    /boot   noauto  on  on  off on  off on  off -none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/grub   /grub   on  on  on  off on  off on  off -none
]0;root@epp: /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache

root@epp:/etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache# cat rpool 
rpool   /   off on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT  none    off on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt    /   on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/srv    /srv    on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/usr    /usr    off on  on  on  on  off on  off -none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/usr/local  /usr/local  on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var    /var    off on  on  on  on  off on  off -none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/games  /var/games  on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/lib    /var/lib    on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/lib/AccountsService    /var/lib/AccountsService    on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/lib/NetworkManager /var/lib/NetworkManager on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/lib/apt    /var/lib/apt    on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/lib/dpkg   /var/lib/dpkg   on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/log    /var/log    on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/mail   /var/mail   on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/snap   /var/snap   on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/spool  /var/spool  on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_mh9hqt/var/www    /var/www    on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/USERDATA  /   off on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
rpool/USERDATA/root_skth53  /root   on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -none
rpool/USERDATA/vince_skth53 /home/vince on  on  on  on  on  off on  off -   none
]0;root@epp: /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache


> lsbpl
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop1    7:1    0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop2    7:2    0 161.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
loop3    7:3    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop5    7:5    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop6    7:6    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9721
loop7    7:7    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1932
loop8    7:8    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
loop9    7:9    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9607
loop10   7:10   0 217.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop11   7:11   0  50.7M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/481
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
sda2   8:2    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part 
sda4   8:4    0 233.5G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk 
sdb1   8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot/efi3
sdb2   8:18   0     2G  0 part 
sdb3   8:19   0     2G  0 part 
sdb4   8:20   0 233.5G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 238.5G  0 disk 
sdc1   8:33   0     1G  0 part /boot/efi2
sdc2   8:34   0     2G  0 part 
sdc3   8:35   0     2G  0 part 
sdc4   8:36   0 233.5G  0 part 
sdc5   8:37   0     8M  0 part 


> zpool status
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 00:00:00 with 0 errors on Sun Oct 25 13:14:56 2020
config:
    NAME                                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool                                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-DEM28-B56M41BW1DC-27_YCA12002130360020-part3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-TS256GSSD420I_F645180016-part3                ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-TS256GSSD420I_F645180017-part3                ONLINE       0     0     0
errors: No known data errors
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 150G in 0 days 00:20:04 with 0 errors on Thu Oct 29 15:00:34 2020
config:
    NAME                                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-TS256GSSD420I_F645180016-part4                ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-TS256GSSD420I_F645180017-part4                ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-DEM28-B56M41BW1DC-27_YCA12002130360020-part4  ONLINE       0     0     0
errors: No known data errors



>find /boot -print
/boot
/boot/initrd.img
/boot/vmlinuz.old
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic
/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
/boot/initrd.img.old
/boot/efi2
/boot/efi2/EFI
/boot/efi2/EFI/BOOT
/boot/efi2/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
/boot/efi2/EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi
/boot/efi2/EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi
/boot/efi2/EFI/ubuntu-2
/boot/efi2/EFI/ubuntu-2/grubx64.efi
/boot/efi2/EFI/ubuntu-2/shimx64.efi
/boot/efi2/EFI/ubuntu-2/mmx64.efi
/boot/efi2/EFI/ubuntu-2/BOOTX64.CSV
/boot/efi2/EFI/ubuntu-2/grub.cfg
/boot/config-5.4.0-52-generic
/boot/System.map-5.4.0-52-generic
/boot/grub
/boot/grub/grubenv
/boot/grub/unicode.pf2
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fat.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsefimmap.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zfscrypt.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/load.cfg
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/exfat.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rsa.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/exfctest.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_md4.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/shim_lock.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ctz_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ext2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix3.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/reiserfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/moddep.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/aout.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/archelp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_sun.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xnu.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/extcmd.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid09.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/priority_queue.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ldm.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsmmap.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rmd160.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tftp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/videoinfo.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cryptodisk.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tga.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pbkdf2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/scsi.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/halt.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/macho.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbls.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/loadenv.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsacpi.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linux16.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_seed.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsefisystab.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pbkdf2_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/nativedisk.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/search_fs_uuid.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/raid5rec.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ahci.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid09_be.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/setjmp_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ufs1.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/sleep_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_bochs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bitmap_scale.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gzio.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/iso9660.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cpuid.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_ftdi.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_plan.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mdraid1x.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_gpt.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/all_video.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/datehook.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/f2fs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha256.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/elf.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/probe.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix_be.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_camellia.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha1.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/acpi.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbtime.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/random.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/div_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lzopio.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_sha512.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gettext.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mmap.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_pl2303.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_whirlpool.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/smbios.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/appleldr.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pata.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/date.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/partmap.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/legacy_password_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm_background.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fixvideo.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tpm.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/boot.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/testload.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hello.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mul_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/keylayouts.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbtable.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/datetime.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_md5.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_fb.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/squash4.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efi_uga.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/syslinuxcfg.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cmp_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/memrw.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/search_label.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/afs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/echo.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/affs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efi_gop.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/wrmsr.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_dsa.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_colors.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/adler32.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_apple.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/morse.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_blowfish.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/nilfs2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pgp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xnu_uuid.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/relocator.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/font.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/at_keyboard.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bitmap.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linux.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/videotest.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_crc.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zfsinfo.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ehci.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix3_be.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/password.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/help.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/true.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hdparm.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/time.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/read.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usb_keyboard.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cmp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/pcidump.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/odc.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/disk.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm_menu.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/offsetio.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/legacycfg.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/sfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/png.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_dvh.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cmdline_cat_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lvm.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/jpeg.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxterm.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tar.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rijndael.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/configfile.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/newc.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbmemc.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/strtoull_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_bsd.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/blocklist.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/net.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_amiga.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linuxefi.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/keystatus.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/serial.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/mpi.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_idea.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usb.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bufio.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/file.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zstd.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/search.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lsefi.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/shift_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/udf.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/test_blockarg.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efifwsetup.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hfsplus.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/reboot.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/testspeed.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/trig.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bswap_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xzio.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cat.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_twofish.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cpio.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/diskfilter.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/play.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/http.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/macbless.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minicmd.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/minix2_be.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/bsd.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/functional_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hexdump.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/verifiers.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/sleep.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/setpci.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/setjmp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/jfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ufs2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/eval.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_tiger.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminfo.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/uhci.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/iorw.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/loopback.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/signature_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lssal.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ufs1_be.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/xnu_uuid_test.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_arcfour.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/search_fs_file.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_des.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video_cirrus.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ls.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_serpent.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fshelp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cpio_be.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbtest.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/msdospart.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/btrfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/div.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/backtrace.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_sunpc.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ohci.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbms.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_rfc2268.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/lspci.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ata.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/progress.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_usbdebug.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gcry_cast5.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/loadbios.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/raid6rec.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efinet.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_acorn.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/memdisk.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_msdos.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/spkmodem.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hfspluscomp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntfscomp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/romfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/tr.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hashsum.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/chain.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/usbserial_common.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/procfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crc64.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gptsync.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/dm_nv.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/regexp.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cbfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/videotest_checksum.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/cs5536.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/luks.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/gfxmenu.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/hfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/geli.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/password_pbkdf2.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/rdmsr.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/part_dfly.mod
/boot/grub/fonts
/boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2
/boot/efi
/boot/efi/grub
/boot/vmlinuz
/boot/efi3 removed to get under 30000 characters.
```

Comment: Maybe this is related to this?  https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5837570.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that GRUB can't deal with the newer features included in the default zpool create from Ubuntu 20.04.
Try creating the pool without any features turned on eg
zpool create -d bpool /dev/sda